# Is $\delta:C_2[0,1]\to \Bbb{R}, \delta(f)=f(0)$ discontinuous?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Is the functional $\delta:C_{2}[-1,1]\to \Bbb{R}, \delta(f)=f(0)$ with $L_2$ norm discontinuous?

I understood I should show whether or not the functional is unbounded, but I can't seem to understand how to use the fact that $f\in C_{2}[-1,1]$. I am still trying to find a series of functions with the right properties.

I think I should take a function $f_n$ with $||f_n||\to 0$ and $||f_n||\ne 0$ while $f_n(0)$ is bounded. Any notes?

Comment: The operator is linear, so showing it is discontinuous boils down to showing that it is unbounded.

Comment: This is where I am stuck.

Comment: And what is $C_2[-1,1]$? An unorthodox way to denote the space of twice continuously differentiable functions on $[-1,1]$? (The standard denotation of that would be $C^2([-1,1])$, or possibly without parentheses $C^2[-1,1]$.)

Comment: No, it is an orthodox way to denote the space of continuous functions equipped with the norm $||f||=\sqrt{\int_{-1}^{1}{|f(x)|^2}dx}<\infty$.

Comment: Never seen that before. But well. Try to find continuous functions with $f(0) = 1$ and $\int_{-1}^1 \lvert f(t)\rvert^2\,dt$ as small as one wants.